# Unpacking PyInstaller packed files

Tags: python

I currently have a PyInstaller packed Elf file and I'm looking to unpack it into the original .py file(s). I have been using PyInstaller Extractor but it appears to be telling the archive is not a PyInstaller archive.

Here is an example of what I've been doing:

```
$ cat main.py
#! /usr/bin/python3
print ("Hello %s" % ("World"))
```

I pack it in the file `dist/main/main` with the command:

```
pyinstaller main.py
```

Which outputs the file:

```
$ file dist/main/main
dist/main/main: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=373ec5dee826653796e927ac3d65c9a8ec7db9da, stripped
```

Now, when I want to unpack it:

```
$ python pyinstxtractor.py dist/main/main
[*] Processing dist/main/main
[*] Error : Unsupported pyinstaller version or not a pyinstaller archive
```

I don't understand why the file cannot be unpacked while I've been looking through many posts telling that this should be possible and I'm beginning to doubt it.

Is the unpacking of the ELF file actually possible?
Am I doing it the right away?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Github page](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor), this script is applicable only for Windows binaries. There is an `archive_viewer.py` script distributed with `pyinstaller` itself that allows to view binary contents and extract it. If you get a `.pyz` file after extraction, use `archive_viewer.py` on it again. IIRC, after all you will get `.pyc` files, which have to be decompiled.

On my system (Manjaro Linux) I've found this script at `/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/utils/cliutils`

It is also available as `pyi-archive_viewer` (at `/usr/bin/pyi-archive_viewer`) after installing to global interpreter.

Comment: I've effectively been able to find the `pyi-archive_viewer` which allowed me to extract the file from the binary and to put it in a `.pyz` file, now, I've tried the script over Windows and Linux on this new file, but the error was the same unfortunately.

Comment: `.pyz` is also could be unpacked with `pyi-archive_veiwer`

Answer (score 4):

Using `pyi-archive_viewer` CLI seems to be the supported solution, i.e. to print only the module names, recursively, and quit instead of prompting:

```py
$ pyi-archive_viewer --log --recursive --brief build/PYZ-00.pyz
['__future__',
 '_aix_support',
---SNIP---
 'zipfile',
 'zipimport']
```

But if you don't want to parse or unsafely `eval()` the CLI output, it *seems* to work to use the library directly:

```py
from PyInstaller.utils.cliutils import archive_viewer

archive = archive_viewer.get_archive('build/PYZ-00.pyz')
output = []
archive_viewer.get_content(archive, recursive=True, brief=True, output=output)
# Now, output is ['__future__', '_aix_support', ---SNIP--- 'zipfile', 'zipimport']
```

This use of the library is undocumented, but it's essentially the same to [what the CLI does](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/e232aaf089d150b085502b97ce0fcf699b45e1b2/PyInstaller/utils/cliutils/archive_viewer.py#L192) given those flags.